# First steps with Raspberry Pi Zero W; How to Connect a Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I managed to copy Raspberrian Buster to my SD card with ApplePi Baker V2 on my MacBook Pro. The other methods: Raspberry Pi Imager and ApplePi Baker v1 seemed to just hang up.

Of course I had a problem writing to the SD card. It seems it makes a difference if you push it in on the bent corner side then the other side. This is a SanDisk Imagemaster Pro 64GB microSD card. Apparently some people have success putting the read/write tab in the middle.

I hooked it up to my Smart TV HDMI, plugged the RP0 PWR Micro USB socket into my convenient Mac Mini’s USB, and it Booted Up and Displayed Beautifully!

One of my problems is that I don’t have all the adapters possible. I don’t have a miniHDMI to HDMI cable. Had to run to Walmart and all they had was a gimmicky HDMI/miniHDMI/microHDMI Tee cable. I like having the right cables for things... Also had to get the microSD card with card adapter.

So I don’t have the right microUSB cable to connect a keyboard to the RP0. I have USB-A to microUSB cables, but the wired keyboards have Integral USB-A cables. Nor do I have a microUSB to USB adapter. I don’t know if I can hook a Powered USB hub to a keyboard and the RP0 and have that work. The only hub I have has a USB3 upstream port, and I don’t have a USB3 to microUSB adapter either.

I can’t be the only one with this problem. I have Bluetooth and other wireless keyboards, but their dongle is USB-A of course.

I hear there is a way to configure the RP0 to SSH to a PC/MAC through USB. I’ll try that. In any case, I need to order cables from Monoprice!

Comment: Could you get to the point? If you have a problem with your keyboard, what does the Smart TV or SD card have to do with it?

Comment: Yes, I don’t have the right USB cable to hook up a keyboard and mouse.

Comment: on a piW you'll need a USB hub to connect keyboard and mouse - you'll need an adapter to connect the HUB to the pi too

Comment: @JaimesBeam "I don’t have the right USB cable to hook up a keyboard and mouse." - then tell us that! Don't spend time describing your Smart TV.

Answer (score 3):

I would set the zero up headless to start with until you have delivery of the correct adapter.

To do this only adds a few extra steps to the imaging you have already done:

1. Add the ssh file to the /boot partition.  With the Mac terminal this is just a case of `touch /Volumes/boot/ssh` With the SD card in.
2. Set up your WiFi network details in wpa_supplicant as per [this article](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/headless.md)
3. Pop the SD card into the Pi and power it on
4. After a few minutes, type `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` in the Mac terminal and you should connect.
5. Run `sudo raspi-config`, change he password, expand the disk and enable anything else you need.

**Note:** You can run the full desktop on the Pi Zero but it’s not the best for anything serious.  If you do run the desktop, go through the above and enable VNC.  You can then use the RealVNC client for the Mac to get to the desktop.